# Maven seems to truncate SQL import / misinterpret parameters under Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, maven

I have a mavenized build (maven3) which has a module to load a mySQL database dump. This works fine under Windows, but not under Linux.

Running maven with the -X switch, it generates the following output:

```
[DEBUG] Using mysql at /usr/bin/mysql
[DEBUG] Command to execute: mysql -uMYUSER --password=**** -hlocalhost --quick --max_allowed_packet=16M --default-character-set=utf8 -e "source /this/path/to/my/database/dump/is/longer/than/70/characters/the_dump.sql"
[ERROR] ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name '/this/path/to/my/database/dump/is/longer/than/70/characters/the_dump.'
```

If I run the debug output on the commandline directly, the the_dump.sql script works fine. My guess is that Maven is not recognizing the parameters correctly, and/or truncating them (note that the second parameter is truncated at 70 characters in the error message). I can't afford to have the build failing under Windows - due to certain commands in the database script, it can't run correctly by passing it into mysql with a "<" pipe.

Here is the relevant pom snippet:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>META-INF</directory>
            <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${dumps.target.dir}</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>my.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>db-dumps-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <databasesToDump>${db.schemas.to.dump}</databasesToDump>
                <documentStoreFolder>${documentstore.location}</documentStoreFolder>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../${dumps.target.dir}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>dump-database</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>dump-db</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>my.maven.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>db-dumps-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>create-database</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>create-db</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <inherited>false</inherited>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And the execute snippet from the db-dumps-maven-plugin:

```
@Override
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {

    final Set<String> dumpsToInsertLowerCase = evaluateDumpsToInsert();

    final List<File> sqlFiles = findFiles(folderWithDumps, ".sql", dumpsToInsertLowerCase);
    getLog().info("Inserting dumps: " + sqlFiles);

    for (final File sqlFile : sqlFiles) {
        String createCommand = "mysql -u%s --password=%s -h%s --quick --max_allowed_packet=16M --default-character-set=utf8 -e \"source %s\"";
        Object[] createArgs = {username, password, hostname, sqlFile.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/")};
        executeCommand(createCommand, createArgs);
    }
}

public void executeCommand(final String command, final Object[] arguments) {

    final String commandToExecute = String.format(command, arguments);
    mavenPlugin.getLog().debug("Command to execute: " + commandToExecute);

    try {
        final Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToExecute);

        final InputStream inputStream = child.getInputStream();
        readAndCloseStream(inputStream, false);

        final InputStream errorStream = child.getErrorStream();
        readAndCloseStream(errorStream, true);

        // prevent leaking file descriptors, close stream
        try {
            child.getOutputStream().close();
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            mavenPlugin.getLog().warn("Unable to close stream. " + ioe);
        }

        // check return value
        // 0 means a normal program termination
        final int exitValue = child.exitValue();
        if (exitValue != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Executing command failed. Exit code: " + exitValue);
        }

    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Any idea why this happens, and how to make maven correctly interpret the source command?

Comment: Can you show the pom.xml how it looks like there?

Comment: @khmarbaise Added snippets from pom.xml & maven plugin source - does this help?

Comment: it looks like it is looking for a database name, but you're not specifying it. where do you expect it should get the database name from?

Comment: @eis there's a config file which is parsed and the database names read from there (I may have stripped too much code when condensing) - the path is however parsed correctly, and also appears in truncated form in the debug message.

Comment: @webmage I understand that path to the SQL dump file is parsed correctly, but according to the error message, it is trying to use the path to dump as a database name, which is wrong. You usually would specify the database name as a separate parameter, and I'm not seeing that. It would look like mysql client is not seeing that either.

Comment: @eis the script contains the create database if not exists / use database statements. This works fine with typical 'source /path/to/mydb' at the MySQL command line. One possible explanation may be that maven is causing the quotes to be interpreted incorrectly, and as a result the path is interpreted as a DB name instead of as a path - in which case the question would be how to correctly issue / escape a source statement so that maven doesn't misinterpret the database path as a database name, and read in the correct source.